# How to reference column of results of function from subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to come up with a query that counts rows grouped by year, that I've to get from TIMESTAMP, and airline_id. So far I've come up with this:

```
SELECT airline_id, extract(year from departure)::integer as year,
(SELECT count(*) FROM tickets AS t2 LEFT JOIN flights AS f2 ON t2.flight_id = f2.flight_id WHERE extract(year from f2.departure) = year AND f2.airline_id = f.airline_id)
FROM tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN flights AS f ON t.flight_id = f.flight_id
GROUP BY airline_id, year
ORDER BY airline_id ASC, year ASC;
```

It seems it would work fine, except it throws this error:

> ERROR: column "year" does not exist

I've tried referencing it as:

```
SELECT airline_id, extract(year from departure)::integer as year,
(SELECT count(*) FROM tickets AS t2 LEFT JOIN flights AS f2 ON t2.flight_id = f2.flight_id WHERE extract(year from f2.departure) = t.year AND f2.airline_id = f.airline_id)
FROM tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN flights AS f ON t.flight_id = f.flight_id
GROUP BY airline_id, year
ORDER BY airline_id ASC, year ASC;
```

But it does the same thing. You also can't call the function again, because

> ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "f.departure" from outer query

So how should I reference the column "year" from subquery?

Comment: It would be nice if you create an SQL fiddle with the schema (or at least part of it) for your question.
http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Edit your question and desicribe what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I'll definitely keep them in mind when asking next time. This time Gordon answered before I improved my question. Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this query:

```
SELECT f.airline_id,  -- I speculate that the airline comes from the flights table
       extract(year from f.departure) as year,
       COUNT(*)
FROM tickets t LEFT JOIN
     flights f 
     ON t.flight_id = f.flight_id
GROUP BY f.airline_id, year
ORDER BY airline_id ASC, year ASC;
```

Does it do what you want?  Your subquery appears to be doing nothing useful.

Comment: That indeed did solve my problem. Thank you very much! I should study more about in what order queries get executed. I thought that rows get "destroyed" by grouping them before the count() function gets executed. I've got so caught up in trying to get the subquery working that I didn't give a second thought to this!